# Cronjob is working, but my Script wont load in cron

Tags: linux, bash, cron, debian

My cron is working(Cron.log below) and my script is working too. But Cron wont load the script every 2 Minutes.

Cron.log:

```html
Apr  3 01:02:01 Debian-78-wheezy-64-minimal /USR/SBIN/CRON[11777]: (mc) CMD (mc /home/mctw2/crash-script)
Apr  3 01:04:01 Debian-78-wheezy-64-minimal /USR/SBIN/CRON[1754]: (mc) CMD (mc /home/mctw2/crash-script)
Apr  3 01:06:01 Debian-78-wheezy-64-minimal /USR/SBIN/CRON[15086]: (mc) CMD (mc /home/mctw2/crash-script)
Apr  3 01:06:49 Debian-78-wheezy-64-minimal crontab[5657]: (root) BEGIN EDIT (root)
Apr  3 01:06:54 Debian-78-wheezy-64-minimal crontab[5657]: (root) END EDIT (root)
Apr  3 01:06:59 Debian-78-wheezy-64-minimal crontab[19549]: (mc) BEGIN EDIT (mc)
Apr  3 01:08:01 Debian-78-wheezy-64-minimal /USR/SBIN/CRON[9566]: (mc) CMD (mc /home/mctw2/crash-script)
Apr  3 01:08:21 Debian-78-wheezy-64-minimal crontab[19549]: (mc) END EDIT (mc)
Apr  3 01:08:26 Debian-78-wheezy-64-minimal crontab[12341]: (mc) BEGIN EDIT (mc)
Apr  3 01:09:01 Debian-78-wheezy-64-minimal /USR/SBIN/CRON[7312]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime ] && [ -x /usr/lib/php5/sessionclean ] && [ -d /var/lib/php5 ] && /usr/lib/php5/sessionclean /var/lib/php5 $(/usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime))
Apr  3 01:10:01 Debian-78-wheezy-64-minimal /USR/SBIN/CRON[29224]: (mc) CMD (mc /home/mctw2/crash-script)
Apr  3 01:10:45 Debian-78-wheezy-64-minimal crontab[12341]: (mc) END EDIT (mc)
Apr  3 01:12:01 Debian-78-wheezy-64-minimal /USR/SBIN/CRON[4285]: (mc) CMD (mc /home/mctw2/crash-script)
Apr  3 01:14:01 Debian-78-wheezy-64-minimal /USR/SBIN/CRON[12549]: (mc) CMD (mc /home/mctw2/crash-script)
Apr  3 01:16:01 Debian-78-wheezy-64-minimal /USR/SBIN/CRON[2767]: (mc) CMD (mc /home/mctw2/crash-script)
Apr  3 01:17:01 Debian-78-wheezy-64-minimal /USR/SBIN/CRON[18323]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
```

and here is my Script:

```
#!/bin/bash

SERVER=`ps ax | grep FTBServer-1.6.4-965.jar | grep -v grep | wc -l`

if [ $SERVER -eq 1 ]

then

exit

else

cd /home/mctw2/ ; screen -a -m -d -s mctw2 ./ServerStart.sh

fi
```

and my crontab at least:

```
*/2 * * * * mc /home/mctw2/crash-script
```

How can I make it work?

Comment: Based on your previous question, I presume that the line is in `/etc/crontab`, which as you know uses a different syntax than a user crontab. Please update your question to make that clear (don't assume anyone has read the other question).

Comment: Sry but i dont get what you mean. in my /etc/crontab file is nothing only when i used crontab -e on my user mc, rly sry but im totaly new in cron and its confusing me more and more

Comment: So you installed that crontab using `crontab -e`? In that case, the problem is that a *user* crontab doesn't require (or allow) a field for the user name. Delete the `mc`.

Comment: @KeithThompson: added as community wiki answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your crontab entry

```
*/2 * * * * mc /home/mctw2/crash-script
```

contains the username `mc` in the 6th column as appropriate for system-level crontabs as in `/etc/crontab`.

However the format for per-user crontabs as edited using `crontab -e` is the following:

```
*/2 * * * * /home/mctw2/crash-script
```

Comment: I edited the crontab file now like you said with crontab -e on the user mc. But still my script doesn't want to start... Same error as above... I dont know what iam doing wrong T_T I just want that my gameserver restarts automaticly when its crash(sry for my bad english) Edit: need i to add at the contrab entry like this eventually because its a .sh file? */2 * * * * /home/mctw2/crash-script.sh

Comment: @oRxx: if it is called `crash-script.sh`, then of course you'll have to write it like that. file extensions are in no way magical in unix/linux as they are in dos/windows.

Comment: Thank you OMG you helped me alot dudes <3 <3 <3 It's working now like i said it was the .sh that was missing... Yeah and thank you realy alot i wasted 2 weeks of my life searching for an answer OMFG T_T Cause in a Tutorial it was like so for a script :)